# How should I model my database - cannot decide on multiple options

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I apologize if this might be a rather beginner-level-question.
For my database design, I have worked out multiple options but cannot decide on which one I should implement. I am using `10.4.17-MariaDB`.

### The basic idea:

I have a Table called `Article` in which I want to store simple fields such as `name` (e.g. varchar), `description` (e.g. varchar), ..., etc. also more complex information like `Producer`, `Price` and so on.

I have worked out the following:

### Implementation I (using just a FK)

```
Table: Article
| id (auto_inkr.) | fk_producer | ... |
| --------------- | ----------- | --- |
| 1               | 1           | ... |
| 2               | 1           | ... |
| 3               | 2           | ... |
| ...             | ...         | ... |
```

As defined, `Producer(id: 1)`, is the `Producer of Articles (1, 2, ...?)`.

### Implementation II (using a lookup table)

```
Table: Article
| id (auto_inkr.)   | fk_article_producer | ... |
| ----------------- | ------------------- | --- |
| 1                 | 1                   | ... |
| 2                 | 1                   | ... |
| 3                 | 2                   | ... |
| ...               | ...                 | ... |
```

```
Table: Article Producer
| id (auto_inkr.)   | article_fk  | producer_fk |
| ----------------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1                 | 1           | 1           |
| 2                 | 2           | 1           |
| 3                 | 3           | 2           |
| ...               | ...         | ...         |
```

In this case here, I have implemented a mapping table. This would also allow me to have a `many-to-many` configuration. I don't have to implement it that way - it is up to my backend-code how I store the data.

### Questions

Please keep in mind, that my `Article` table as of now will have like `7+` dependent tables (as shown in the example here: e.g. `Producer`). I want to design it, so I can write an efficient filter-function (query) for my `text- respectively tag-based-search` later on.

- Which design should I choose and why?
- What are the benefits or downsides of these approaches (best practice)?

Comment: What is an `Article` in this context and what is a `Producer`?

Comment: An Article is a physical, sellable Product that you can put in the basket of an e-store. In this context. The Producer is just the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design 2 two is needed when here are multiple producers per article, you need a bridge table between article and producer, so a producer can have multiple articles and an article can have multiple producers

your first is only valid for 1 to 1 reöationships.

so what you you t have **1:1** or **m:n**

Thet will determine, what you need

Comment: Yes, that is what I already figured out. But the question remains: "Can I" or rather "Should I" use design 2 for all of my tables? Regarding querying and performance - would it be better to have the relationship between the two tables in a separate table in every case for a faster lookup or is this just nonsense? Do you get what I mean by that?

Comment: look i don't knpow what reölationship ypu have, so my answer give you the option what to do solution 1 for 1:1 or solution2 for m:n. a briidge table for 1:1 relationships a possible but bring no further information

Comment: The relationship is 1:n (1 Producer -> n Articles). I was just overthinking it, I guess. You are right it does not really add any value. At first, it looked like one may be able to write a more performant query in this case (because you can isolate the essential part for the lookup), but you end up with joins or subqueries anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make a table for each "entity", such as "article" and "producer".  Each such table would have an `id` and a variety of attributes (name, etc).

Then characterize the "relationships" between pairs of those entities and build relations:

- For **one:one**, rethink why you have two separate tables; consider merging the tables together.
- For **one:many**, the "many" table needs a column with the `id` of the "one".  And have an `INDEX` on that column.
- For **many:many**, you need an extra table with *only* two columns, namely an id into each of the other tables.  (Note:  it is a waste to have a new `id` for this column.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table )

A `FOREIGN KEY` does two things: it provides a constraint that checks data integrity, and it makes sure there is a suitable `INDEX` (for performance).  (Foreign keys are desirable, but not required.)